# Sitecore Serialization Powershell

Tags: powershell, serialization, sitecore

I need to serialize some Items with Sitecore Powershell Script.

I need to:

- Serialize an Item
- Create a folder in filesystem (`C:/serialisation/1`) and move the results in the serialization folder to this folder

Can someone write how the powershell script will look like? Links to resources about serialization with Powershell will also be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you know about [Sitecore Powershell Extensions](http://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Sitecore_PowerShell_console.aspx).

Serialization of the item:

```
# Serialization
Get-Item -Path "master:\templates\spe\" | Serialize-Item -Recurse
```

Copy files:

```
#copy
Copy-Item -Path C:\fso\20110314.log -Destination c:\fsox\mylog.log
```

And you can find an explanation in this [video Sitecore PowerShell Extensions - Packages and Serialization](http://michaellwest.blogspot.com/2013/08/SPE-PackagesAndSerialization.html).

And here is a blog post explaining [serialization and deserialization with Sitecore Powershell Extensions](http://www.cognifide.com/blogs/sitecore/serialization-and-deserialization-with-sitecore-powershell-extensions/).

Answer (score 1):

You can serialize Powershell objects with Export-CLIXML.

run Get-Help Export-CLIXML -full for more information.